# Java: How to use Deque's?

Tags: java, deque

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html

I am learning about to how use this object.

> `boolean   add(E e)`
>
> Inserts the specified element into the queue represented by this deque
>   (in other words, at the tail of this deque) if it is possible to do so
>   immediately without violating capacity restrictions, returning true
>   upon success and throwing an `IllegalStateException` ***if no space is
>   currently available.***

I am confused on 'if no space is currently available.' I don't see anything where you set the size, does it mean No space as in, no JVM?

I am looking into how to make a Deque that holds 5 values and I want to add one and remove the oldest when it is at 5.

I hope this makes sense, if not please ask me to elaborate and I will.

Thanks a lot SOF community!

Comment: "I don't see anything where you set the size" - that's because it's implementation-specific. From the docs: "Most Deque implementations place no fixed limits on the number of elements they may contain, but this interface supports capacity-restricted deques as well as those with no fixed size limit." See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html for example.

Comment: Deque is an interface, if you look at the implementing classes, they have a constructor in which you can specify an initial capacity

Comment: *I am looking into how to make a Deque*: don't *create* a Deque implementation. Just *use* one in your class, and remove the oldest element before adding one if the size limit is reached..

Answer (score 0):

How to use Deque (and then its just about wrapping this to methods you wish to support with few `if` statements):

```
Deque<String> deq = new LinkedList<>(); //to have a fixed size, use ArrayDeque<E>
deq.addFirst("a");
System.out.println(deq.peekFirst()); //a - just take a look, do not remove

deq.addFirst("b");
System.out.println(deq.peekFirst()); //b
System.out.println(deq.peekLast()); //a

deq.addLast("c");
System.out.println(deq.peekLast()); //c

deq.add("d");
System.out.println(deq.peekLast()); //d 

System.out.println(deq.pollLast()); //d - return and remove
System.out.println(deq.pollLast()); //c
```

If you want to have some kind of circular buffer, you may want to use this Apache Commons collection instead - [CircularFifoBuffer](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.2/org/apache/commons/collections/buffer/CircularFifoBuffer.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it with a `Deque` - it's simple but I think it addresses the problem you are trying to solve.

```
public class DequeExample {
    Deque<Integer> deque = new ArrayDeque<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DequeExample dequeExample = new DequeExample();

        // adding elements
        for( int idx = 0; idx < 9; idx++){
            dequeExample.addNewest(idx);
        }
    }

    private void addNewest(int newest){
        if(deque.size() == 5){
            System.out.println("Queue at capacity, removing element before adding more.");
            Integer e = deque.removeLast();
            System.out.println("Removed: " + e);
        }

        deque.push(newest);
        System.out.println("Added: " + newest );
        System.out.println(deque);
    }
}
```